# ASP.NET MVC 4 Cross-Subdomain Authentication. Can't sign out

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, subdomain, logout, httpcookie

So I have a site sitting on URL "mysite.com" and another site on "subdomain.mysite.com". User accounts are stored in "mysite.com", so when I need to log in on "subdomain.mysite.com" I take the user to "mysite.com", they enter their credentials authenticate them normally and make sure that the authentication cookie is usable in "subdomain.mysite.com" by setting the `domain` in the cookie as follows:

```
HttpCookie cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(username, true);
cookie.Domain = ".mysite.com";
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Then I redirect them back to "subdomain.mysite.com" and the user is thankfully authenticated there.

Everything works well except when logging out. When the user tries to log out from any site, I remove the authentication cookie as expected:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

But for some reason the cookie is not being removed, the user stays logged in.

I have tried deleting the cookie directly using `Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]` but still nothing. Chrome is holding on to the cookie really tight for some reason: I can see it in Chrome's developer tools.

What am I doing wrong? Help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, found the solution to the problem.

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
cookie.Domain = ".mysite.com";
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

As you can see, two things happen here:

- I'm explicitly setting the domain again for the cookie I'm handling. Apparently you have to tell the browser the domain context or it simply won't find the cookie.

- Instead of removing the cookie, I'm simply expiring it.

Comment: there's a solution using only web.config configured properly?